# PHP Match Multipline Line with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match multiple lines of a document using a regex in PHP. I'm aware of the \s option, but somehow I am not able to figure out the correct regular expression (using the online regex test tools).

The file is an iCal File and looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
LAST-MODIFIED:20140203T092537Z
CREATED:20140101T161157Z
DTSTART:20140220T150000Z
DTSTAMP:20140203T092537Z
DTEND:20140220T170000Z
SUMMARY:Summary of Event
UID:appointment_27140
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
LAST-MODIFIED:20140203T092537Z
CREATED:20140101T161157Z
DTSTART:20140221T070000Z
DTSTAMP:20140203T092537Z
DTEND:20140221T130000Z
SUMMARY:Event 2
UID:appointment_27135
LOCATION:TINF11B2
END:VEVENT
```

I would like to match a whole event (from BEGIN:EVENT to END:EVENT) if it contains certain keywords in the Event Summary.

I thought the regex for matching the second event in the above iCal would look similar to this:

`/BEGIN:VEVENT(.*)Event 2(.*)END:VEVENT/s`

Comment: Why not work with an iCal parser or class such that you can work with the field you are interested directly?

Comment: It's just a little php script, that fixes a bug in my universities calendar. 
With this extension it should also be able to filter out certain lectures. It's really just deleting a couple of events in the original iCal. I don't think there is the need to use an iCal Parser as I am not really trying to get information out of the iCal/modfiy the iCal heavily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(BEGIN:VEVENT(?:(?!BEGIN:VEVENT).)*Event 2.*?END:VEVENT)
```

1. Capture the whole event text
2. Match string "BEGIN:VEVENT",
3. Eat up and don't capture zero or more characters that aren't look-ahead "BEGIN:VEVENT",
4. Match string "Event 2",
5. Eat up zero or more characters non-greedy,
6. Match string "END:VEVENT"

**Regex Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/aK6lR4

**PHP Code:**

```
//$events contains the file text
$search = 'Event 2';
$matches = array();
$found = preg_match('/BEGIN:VEVENT(?:(?!BEGIN:VEVENT).)*' . $search . '.*?END:VEVENT/s', $events, $matches);
if ($found === 1) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Alternatively you can use preg_match_all to match more than one event.  $matches[0] will be an array instead of a string and $found will contain the number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that:

```
$kw = 'Event 2';

$pattern = sprintf('~BEGIN:([^\r\n]+)\R((?>[^E%s]++|\B[E%s]|(?!END:\1)%s(?!%s)|(?!%s)E(?!ND:\1))+)%s(?2)END:\1~',
                  $kw[0], $kw[0], $kw[0], substr($kw,1), $kw, $kw);

preg_match_all($pattern, $iCalContent, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question on StackOverflow:
[RegEx: can't figure out the expression to match lines with individual events and match only those containing certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032018/regex-cant-figure-out-the-expression-to-match-lines-with-individual-events-and?rq=1)

Here is a link to an online-demo:
http://regex101.com/r/uX3gV6

Comment: True, but there's a [better answer right here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21681729/20938).  Specifically, you can use `.` instead of `[\s\S]`, and it should go after the lookahead, not before.